# Debugging FuseESB application in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, apache-karaf, fuseesb, apache-servicemix

Fuse ESB uses karaf server with OSGi.

for the code if anybody has steps to get the debugger for the application it will help.

I am currently using Eclipse Indigo.
As OSGi is used we are using Maven to build the same.

Which plugin will help for Karaf with OSGi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java allows you to remote debug any JVM running.

So if you start the ESB with a debug argument, then it will run in debug mode listening on port 5005.

```
davsclaus:/opt/fuse-esb-7.0.1.fuse-084$ bin/fuseesb debug
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Then you can do remote debugging from Eclipse using that port number. This is standard Java remote debugging, and Eclipse has a wizard for that already. Its the debug wizard which has a remote debug functionality.

Comment: There is some details here as well: http://servicemix.apache.org/remote-debugging-servicemix-in-eclipse.html

Comment: Can you mark this questions as answered, since you got it working?

Comment: The old SMX link works no longer - use this from Karaf instead - http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/developers-guide/debugging.html

Answer (score 3):

You just need to put the following line in the Fuse ESB startup script (e.g. fuseesb.bat or karaf.bat):

set KARAF_DEBUG=true

After that Fuse ESB will start in debug mode using 5005 port.

Answer (score 1):

1) just run $fuse debug (jboss fuse 6.1.0 version) debug port is 5005, 
2) in eclipse or jboss dev studio do following
    i) run
    ii) debug configuration
    iii) remote java application -> create new
    iv) host: localhost, port : 5005
     v) click on debug
3) put breakpoints in java classes